# Monkey patching a library until the OSS project releases a patch

Tags: java, reflection, aop, bcel

I am using a well established piece of open source library in my code, I have discovered a bug in it and have reported it to the community. However I am not really qualified to fix the bug as I would not know all the side effects of changing the code. The bug is in a private function of a final class. The framework passed me an already instantiated version of that class to my function. I am wondering if there is any suitable Monkey patching technique I can use to fix that instance of that class for the duration that I need it. This would limit any potential undesirable side effects. I understand that there are techniques that might help such as Aspect Orientated Programming, Byte Code Manipulation or reflection. What should I be doing in this situation?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: If you are not qualified to change the (open-)source itself, how will you change it with monkey patching (which ever technique you use)?

Comment: That's a fair question - my reasoning is that if I change it on just one instance I am assuming I will have less risk of an unexpected side effect. If I change the source code, there are far more cases (instances) where the effects could be felt.

Comment: Sorry for my late attention. Would it be a solution for you if you make a proxy-class that holds the final object you cannot modify and you implement the interface of it and handle the correct working methods to the object and handle the incorrect methods yourself? If the final class has no interface than it's maybe easier if you grab the source of the library and remove the "final" from the class, so you can extend it.